USB memory devices to be shared on MacOS 10.7.10
I have a Mac (BSD UNIX:  I believe that USB devices are mounted at /Volumes.
Is there a clever method to ensure that all USB memory devices are shared at a consistent location on the network automatically when they are plugged in?

Mac has SAMBA UI:
